# Why does Fleury's algorithm have to return to the starting node?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Recently, I am reading the Fleury's Algorithm part of the document [1]. There is a sentence on page 3 of this document:

> Note that, when the algorithm terminates, we must return to $v_{start}$ because every vertex has an even degree.

I don't understand why we must return to $v_{start}$. Could anyone please teach me?

---

1. [Eulerian circuits](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~ethan/TA/251/eulerian.pdf) by Ethan Kim (accessed Oct 14, 2016)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you end up at a vertex different from the start. You may have visited the vertex before, say $k$ times. Each time you visited the vertex you used up one edge to enter it and one edge to leave it. So $2k$ edges, an even number. When you enter it for the last time, you used up $2k+1$ edges, an odd number. Since the degree of all nodes is even, there must be an edge left over which you can leave the vertex and the algorithm wouldn't have stopped.

The start vertex is special because you don't need to enter it to visit it the first time (right at the start).

Note that a graph can also be eulerian if it has exactly two vertices with odd degree. Then you have to choose one of them as a start vertex and you will end up at the other odd-degree vertex at the end of the algorithm. I leave it to you to prove why this is the case.

Comment: I have a question. We say that a graph is Eulerian if it possesses an Eulerian cycle [1, page3]. A connected graph contains an Eulerian cycle if and only if every vertex has even degree [1, Theorem 1.1]. Are you sure "a graph can also be eulerian if it has exactly two vertices with odd degree"? --- Reference: [1] C. Moore and S. Mertens, *The Nature of Computation*, Oxford University Press, 2015.